# font awesome anchor tags on footer not clickable from mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, font-awesome

I have notices a weird problem with my site which I recently hosted. The problem is with the font awesome anchor tags on the footer at the bottom of the page. It works fine when I view them from my computer and even in the developer mode in chrome.

When I view my website on my mobile, on some occasions the footer links DO NOT work on the index.html page. If I have clicked on any of the links to the subsections of the index.html from the nav bar (About, Portfolio or Project) prior to clicking on the footer icons they  DON'T WORK. NOTE: This ONLY OCCURS when the site is viewed with mobiles. The website is mentioned below. If you have any suggestions for improvements regarding any other aspects please let me know. Thanks!

website: http://www.maheenul.com

The code pen link is : https://codepen.io/maheenul/pen/QBLVxz?editors=1010
Note: I could not replicate the problem in code pen because the hrefs I used refer to filename and hence they wont work on code pen.

```
<footer class="footer">
            <div class="container footer-content">
                <span class="contact-group">
                    <a href="https://github.com/maheenul" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/maheenul/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a href="mailto:maheenul@gmail.com"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
                </span>
                <span class="trademark">
                    &copy 2018 Maheenul
                </span>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

To replicate the problem please follow the following steps on my website (chrome): 
load the main page (index.html) -> click on "project" in nav bar -> scroll up to the nav -> click on project again-> now scroll to the footer at the bottom -> try clicking my linkedin icon on the footer.

Comment: Please include code, along with what attempts you've made.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not only on an external site. When you fix your problem and update your website, this question will not be useful to anyone else.

Comment: not sure what exactly is your problem, just out of curiosity i checked your website on my phone, all the link works fine !!!

Comment: load the main page -> click on project -> scroll up to the nav -> click on project again->  now scroll to the footer at the bottom -> try clicking my linkedin icon on the footer.